# add_post_meta() & update_post_meta()

Tags: metabox

I am learning WordPress Plugin Development. I need to store Metabox values which are related to Custom Post.

In this regard where should I use add_post_meta() & where should I use update_post_meta() ?

Answer (score 2):

**add_post_meta()** : Adds a meta field to the given post.

Below is the example,

```
<?php

$post_id = 1;
$meta_key = '_test';
$meta_value = 'this is a test';
$unique = true;

add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
```

**update_post_meta()** : if the given key already exists among custom fields of the specified post, another custom field with the same key is added unless the $unique argument is set to true, in which case, no changes are made. **If you want to update the value of an existing key, use the update_post_meta() function**

It will fire when a post type is saved or updated, several actions fire, any of which might be appropriate to hook into in order to save the entered values.

Below is the example,

```
function wporg_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wporg_field', $_POST ) ) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_wporg_meta_key',
            $_POST['wporg_field']
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wporg_save_postdata' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Anshali Tejani. Where should I use `add_post_meta()` ?

Comment: @Foysal, add_post_meta() , is used for if you want to store some data in your custom field then it stored in database **postmeta** table. like you have to store car name in 

$meta_key = 'mycar'; $meta_value = 'Audi';
$meta_key = 'mycar'; $meta_value = 'ferrari';

**'mycar'** field name is created in **postmeta** table in Wordpress! and it store under the meta_key field, meta_value field store **Ferrari, Audi etc.**